# How to read ArrayList<String> field from database with PostgreSQL JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm having an issue with getting the value of stored `ArrayList<String>` as `VARCHAR[]` in the database.

Somehow, when I'm debugging, I can see that the value returning from the database is:

[image]

I am expecting to store an `ArrayList<String>` by converting it to `VARCHAR[]` and when reading from the DB I expect to convert `VARCHAR[]` to `ArrayList<String>`

Code:

```java
 public Message<ArrayList<String>> getPlayersInSession(Object data) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String sessionCode = (String) data;
        Session session = PostgreSQLJDBC.sessionJDBCInstance().getSession(sessionCode);

        //session.getPlayers() is the problem I have
        return new Message<>(Message.RequestCode.RECEIVE_PLAYERS_IN_SESSION, session.getPlayers());
(Message.RequestCode.RECEIVE_PLAYERS_IN_SESSION, players);
    }
```

```java
public class Session {

    private int _id;
    private String _code;
    private ArrayList<String> _players;
    private ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> _leaderboard;

    public Session() {
        _code = "";
        _players = new ArrayList<>();
        _leaderboard = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    ...

}
```

```java
public class SessionJDBC implements SessionSQL {

    private final Connection _connection;

    public SessionJDBC(String url, String user, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        _connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        if (!sessionTableExists()) createTable();
    }

    @Override
    public void createTable() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE session(" +
                "id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY," +
                "code VARCHAR," +
                "players VARCHAR[]," +
                "leaderboard VARCHAR[]" +
                ")";
        PreparedStatement ps = _connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void addSession(Session session) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO session(code, players, leaderboard)"
                + "VALUES (?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement ps = _connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

        ps.setString(1, session.getCode());
        ps.setArray(2, _connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", session.getPlayers().toArray()));
        ps.setArray(3, _connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", session.getLeaderboard().toArray()));

        ps.executeUpdate();

        ResultSet generatedKeys = ps.getGeneratedKeys();

        if (generatedKeys.next()) {
            session.setId(generatedKeys.getInt(1));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeSession(Session session) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM session WHERE id = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = _connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setInt(1, session.getId());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public Session getSession(String code) throws SQLException {
        return getAllSessions().stream().filter(session -> session.getCode().equals(code)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Session> getAllSessions() throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<Session> array = new ArrayList<>();

        ResultSet result = _connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM session").executeQuery();

        while (result.next()) {
            Session session = new Session();

            session.setCode(result.getString("code"));
            session.setId(result.getInt("id"));
            session.setPlayers(new ArrayList(Collections.singletonList(result.getArray("players"))));
            session.setLeaderboard(new ArrayList(Collections.singletonList(result.getArray("leaderboard"))));

            array.add(session);
        }

        result.close();

        return array;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sessionTableExists() throws SQLException {
        DatabaseMetaData dbm = _connection.getMetaData();
        ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, "session", null);

        return tables.next();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a code example, and a better explanation of the problem, e.g what you expect to happen and what is happening?

Comment: @Dean Updated question.

Comment: Is the problem that the ArrayList only has one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the code example compiles given that the ArrayList shown in the debugger is actually of type `ArrayList<PgArray>` rather than `ArrayList<String>`.

The problem is occurring in these lines:

```
session.setPlayers(new ArrayList(Collections.singletonList(result.getArray("players"))));
session.setLeaderboard(new ArrayList(Collections.singletonList(result.getArray("leaderboard"))));
```

For a start `result.getArray("players")` is returning a [java.sql.Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html) object, more specifically a [PgArray](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgArray.html) implementation. To get the real underlying data you need to do:

```
(String[])result.getArray("players").getArray();
```

The next problem is that you are using `Collections.singletonList()`. What this does is produce an ArrayList with only one element. Instead what you should use is `Arrays.asList`. Full solution:

```
session.setPlayers(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList((String[])result.getArray("players").getArray)));
session.setLeaderboard(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList((String[])result.getArray("leaderboard").getArray)));
```

Another thing that is interesting about this code is that you are selecting all rows from the table and then filtering in memory by streaming over the results. Why not select on the `code` field in an SQL query?

Comment: Amazing! it is indeed solved my problem, now I get the ArrayList like I wanted it to.
And about the selection of all rows, you are right, somehow I haven't thought of that.
Thank you so much